# Automatic sign on - Windows XP SP2 and Windows 2003 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, rdp, terminal

Is it possible to automatically pass logon credentials from XP SP2 to MSTSC.exe (and terminal server 2003).

It seems Vista/XPSP3 & 2008 support doing this out of the box, but XP & 2003 doesn't.

I'm not looking at any third party clients or servers, so Citrix/2X etc isn't an option for me at the moment.

Comment: The thought of doing this creeps me out.  What's so difficult about putting in the password to maintain security?

Comment: To keep things simple - we have 1300 students that can logon to anyone of 800 PCs, which would mean having to logon twice at each PC, once to access local resources and once to access terminal based resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the credentials so that when you run mstsc it connects immediately and doesn't prompt the user. However you still need to enter the credentials the first time you log in. You can't make mstsc pick up the username and password of the logged in user.

JR

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know it is not possible.

However, it is possible to get XP SP3 to use SSO with Windows Server 2008 by following [these instructions](http://www.ravenreport.com/blog/post/Getting-Single-Sign-On-to-work-in-XP-when-connecting-to-a-Windows-2008-Terminal-Server.aspx).  The caveat is that SSO will not work when connecting to a terminal server farm or alias.

Comment: Seriously mate, my question was about 2003 & XP, I even say in the question that Vista/XPSP3 support doing it.  Maybe you didn't read that far?